# getContent triggers even on dragging of selected text

Tags: tinymce

I have this callback in my html:

```
editor.on('getContent', function(e) {
    if ((typeof(obj) !== 'undefined') && (obj !== null)){
        obj.onGetContentEventHandler(e.content);
    }
});
```

When I select some text in the editor and drag the selected part some distance (doesn't have to be dropped to the text, the actual event is triggered as soon as you start dragging), TinyMce will trigger the `getContent`-event!

Now, as you can see in the code snippet above, I have a callback to my application, which will sync the editor text with the application. 
So, if you select 'Hello' from the text 'Hello there' and drag it (doesn't matter where you drop it), the application will think that the text in TinyMce is 'Hello' now, when it in fact still is 'Hello there'!

Is this a bug?

**I would really like to know how to either:**

1. In `editor.on('getContent'...` check for a "This is a dragged selected text"-event and then just skip it. or.....
2. Stop `getContent` from triggering on dragging selected text.

How can I do this?

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObpKvz?editors=1111) where you can try this for yourself!
.
 - Bring the codepen console up if it's not up already.
 - Select some part of the text, like " is a te" or something.
 - In the console you will now see that the `getContent` event fired with your selected text.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

`e.selection` holds a boolean that is true if the event is a selection.

The rest was easy...

```
editor.on('getContent', function(e) {
    if ((typeof(obj) !== 'undefined') && (obj !== null) && !e.selection){
        obj.onGetContentEventHandler(e.content);
    }
});
```